# MapBox Smooth Transition of Resizing Map

Tags: javascript, mapbox, transition, mapbox-gl-js

I have a website for CVOID-19 that displays cases on a MapBox map. One of the buttons on the website hides the case info so you get the the full map. The width transition of the case info box works nicely, but it leaves the map un-resized. Thankfully there is a method conveniently named `map.resize()` that resizes the map into it's appropriate size after the width of the case info box goes down to zero using a `transitionend` event. However the resizing isn't transitioned at all and it ends up looking incredibly janky with the sudden resizing of the map out of no where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with, on the start of the transition you call the map.resize() function every 10 ms, and then you stop the interval once the transition has ended, it ends up looking quite a bit smoother.

```
let mapResizer;

countryPanel.addEventListener("transitionstart", (e) => {
    if (e.target == countryPanel) {
        mapResizer = setInterval(map.resize, 10);
    }
})

countryPanel.addEventListener("transitionend", (e) => {
    if (e.target == countryPanel) {
        if (e.target.classList.contains("hide")) {
            showBtn.hidden = false;
        }
        clearInterval(mapResizer);
    }
})
```

Here is the website displaying the effect when you click the hide UI button (the little arrow pointing to the left): https://people.rit.edu/ajr6974/330/Project%203/

Comment: Another solution to consider is having the sidebar (or whatever it is) as an overlay, so it can just slide out of the way, and the map doesn't have to change in size.

Comment: SteveBennett, While that may work with some use cases, if the user decides to orbit, he's going to find that the center point is not in the center. Weird experience, do not recommend for production.

The 10ms interval works magic in dev environment for me. requestAnimationFrame didn't work well so I'm surprised a basic interval does. Kudos @Alex

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by calling the `easeTo` method add updating the `padding`, e.g

```
map.current?.easeTo({
   padding: {
      left: showFilterPanel ? sizes.sidePanelWidth : 0,
      right: selectedVesselId ? sizes.sidePanelWidth : 0,
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
   },
   duration: 900,
});
```

Demo / source info here:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/offset-vanishing-point-with-padding/